# REST API или MVC

Tags: api, mvc, rest

нужно чтобы веб-приложение и desktop-приложение использовали одну базы данных. Нужно писать Rest API? Или использовать что-то другое?

Comment: Вам нужно сделать API. Каким именно оно будет: REST, WCF, Xml Web Service - не важно. Лучше, конечно, делайте REST - сейчас это стандарт. А потом обращаетесь к этому API из любых других типов приложений (веб, десктоп, мобильное).

Answer (score 4):

Противопоставление `REST API или MVC` звучит так же нелепо, как "приборная панель или двигатель?" – это не противоположности, а сочетаемые элементы.

MVC – это шаблон проектирования, подразумевающий разделение приложения на модель, содержащую в себе бизнес-логику, представление, отвечающее за вывод данных, и контроллер, который обеспечивает связь между моделью и представлением.

HTTP/REST API – это способ взаимодействия отдельных программ и их экземпляров по интернету. Что позволяет, например, модель из MVC вынести на отдельный сервер, и наладить взаимодействие множества отдельных представлений с ней по сети.

В норме для этого разрабатывается свой веб-сервер и API к нему. В принципе, есть и другие варианты – использование готовых веб-сервисов вроде Google Firebase или взаимодействие peer-to-peer или что-то ещё более интересное. У всех вариантов есть много плюсов и минусов, которые будут сильно отличаться в каждой конкретной задаче. Но создание своего сервера с API всё же мейнстримный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Если писать desktop-приложение, то значит нужно разрабатывать свой UI. Страницы HTML/CSS desktop-приложение отображать не будет. С HTML/CSS работает только браузер. Классический MVC выдаёт динамически обновляемые HTML-страницы, а значит не подойдёт для desktop. Решением вопроса является только REST API. В этом случае его сможет использовать и desktop и веб приложение.